# Unwanted space before flalign

Tags: amsmath, align, mathtools

Why is there so much vertical space between the subsection heading and the equation in the following example. How do I get rid of it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\begin{flalign*}
a+b=8 &&\\
c=2 &&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Imad]

Secondly, why is it aligned at the equals sign, even without `&=`? I want both of the lines to be flushed to the left.

Comment: Harish's answer show you how to adjust it, but it usually not recommend to begin a paragraph with a display math equation. If you use it as part of the normal paragraph the spacing is correct.

Comment: As far as your second question as to why the equal signs are aligned is that the `8` and `2` take up the same space and the equations are right aligned since there is no `&` until the end of the line, so then the end of the line _is_ specified as the alignment point.

Comment: Are you sure you need `flalign*`? `\subsection{Subtitle}$a+b=8$\\$c=2$` would do as well. Can you be more explicit about why you need such a layout?

Comment: Sometimes I'll want to align some equations at the equals sign, so I'll need `flalign`. With my second question I was just wondering why my example wasn't flushed to the very left (the `$` were at the wrong places).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reduce `\abovedisplayskip` and put a `&` at the begining and one at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{flalign*}
&a+b=8 &\\
&c=2 &
\end{flalign*}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there are way to set `\abovedisplayskip` so that the space before equations after every heading is reduced?

Comment: @user21760: I don't advice it as it is a overkill (you have to patch the heading command). See comments of egreg and Peter above regarding these things.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that you really want `flalign` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newenvironment{flusheqs}
 {\noindent$\begin{array}{@{}>{\displaystyle}l@{}}}
 {\end{array}$\par}


\begin{document}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\begin{flusheqs}
a+b=8 \\
c=2
\end{flusheqs}
\end{document}
```

[image]