# Problem with amsmath's `gather` environment

Tags: amsmath

I have a lot of math to write so I tried to use `align` inside `gather`. When the column was over I was getting badboxes. So I used two `gather` environments and the output is weird. What is happening and why? How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}



\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
&\text{70}\\
&e^{jz}=\cos z+j\sin z\\
&\cos z=(1/2)(2\cos z)=\\
&=(1/2)(2\cos z+j\sin z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(\cos z+j\sin z+\cos z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(e^{jz}+e^{-jz})
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{207}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
&\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
&\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+K_{p}m(t)]
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{208}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
&\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
&\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}=2\pi K_{f}m(t)\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow \phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos\left[2\pi f_{c}t+2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\right]
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{208}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos\theta(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)]\\
&\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b\\
&\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
&\phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{265}\\
&g(t)=f(t)\ast h(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\\
&j(t)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT_{s})\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}[j(t)]=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}[\delta(t)]e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}



\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
&\text{70}\\
&e^{jz}=\cos z+j\sin z\\
&\cos z=(1/2)(2\cos z)=\\
&=(1/2)(2\cos z+j\sin z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(\cos z+j\sin z+\cos z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(e^{jz}+e^{-jz})
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{207}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
&\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
&\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+K_{p}m(t)]
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{208}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
&\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
&\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}=2\pi K_{f}m(t)\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow \phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos\left[2\pi f_{c}t+2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\right]
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{208}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos\theta(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)]\\
&\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b\\
&\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
&\phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau
\end{aligned}\\
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
&\text{265}\\
&g(t)=f(t)\ast h(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\\
&j(t)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT_{s})\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}[j(t)]=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}[\delta(t)]e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit I:

This is the output with `\raggedcolumns` as proposed in the comments and obviously there are problems concerning the space left in the first column and the height difference between the first and the second column. Also I don't understand why is there a problem in the first place with `gather` environments.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\raggedcolumns

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
&\text{70}\\
&e^{jz}=\cos z+j\sin z\\
&\cos z=(1/2)(2\cos z)=\\
&=(1/2)(2\cos z+j\sin z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(\cos z+j\sin z+\cos z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(e^{jz}+e^{-jz})
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{207}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
&\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
&\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+K_{p}m(t)]
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{208}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
&\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
&\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}=2\pi K_{f}m(t)\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow \phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos\left[2\pi f_{c}t+2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\right]
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{208}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos\theta(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)]\\
&\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b\\
&\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
&\phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau
\end{aligned}\\
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
&\text{265}\\
&g(t)=f(t)\ast h(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\\
&j(t)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT_{s})\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}[j(t)]=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}[\delta(t)]e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this really a *minimal* example?

Comment: Other topic: Don't load `inputenc` with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Why precisely do you need 2 columns?

Comment: Use `\raggedcolumns` to fix this - you haven't provided many places for the columns to break...

Comment: @AndrewSwann I don't understand what is the problem. Also this doesn't solve it. It moves the first column up but not in the same height as the second one. Furthermore it leaves a lot of space in the first column.

Comment: @Bernard I just like two column documents!

Comment: @Jubobs what do you mean? Yes this is the code in which I work on. It had to be big so to behaviour when the first column was full to be obvious .

Comment: Not related, but loading `inputenc` and compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX should be avoided. About the problem: you have been told several times that starting a paragraph with a display environment is wrong.

Comment: You can "balance" the columns by putting a paragraph break before the "gather" make each column equally wrong.  The general underlying problem however is that the ams math environments typeset their contents twice to be able to correctly place the equation numbers, and this double pass plays badly with the height measurements "multicol" is trying to work with.

Comment: The space at the top is coming from `\abovedisplayskip` which is vertical space inserted to offset displayed equations from the preceeding text of the paragraph.  You can switch off as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82241/15925.  However, it looks to me that your are trying to place text material in the math environment - the numbers look more like labels that part of the equation - so you should think of changing your input format.  Also your `aligned` are superfluous - you have already set `fleqn`...

Comment: @AndrewSwann what you propose regarding the vertical space works only if there is text before the `gather` environment. In my case doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this approach, I build each block as a stack (with a 3pt buffer above and below), and then insert a `\vspace{2ex}\par\vfil` after each one.  The `2ex` is the minimum gap between blocks, and the `\vfil` will smooth out the whole look of the column (see alternative approach without this `\vfil` in 2nd part of the answer).  After the final item in your multipage list, you can add a final`\vfil` so as to avoid excessive gapping from a partially filled column.

Within a block, the inter-item gap is specified in advance by `\setstackgap{S}{6pt}`.  A block will not break in two across a column or page boundary, but the `\vfil` solution makes that look not so objectionable.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}

%\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

%\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\stackalignment{l}
\setstackgap{S}{6pt}
\def\SS#1{\noindent\addstackgap[3pt]{\Shortstack{#1}}\vspace{2ex}\par\vfil}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
Preceding text\par
\SS{
\text{70}\\
e^{jz}=\cos z+j\sin z\\
\cos z=(1/2)(2\cos z)=\\
=(1/2)(2\cos z+j\sin z-j\sin z)=\\
=(1/2)(\cos z+j\sin z+\cos z-j\sin z)=\\
=(1/2)(e^{jz}+e^{-jz})
}
\SS{
\text{70}\\
e^{jz}=\cos z+j\sin z\\
\cos z=(1/2)(2\cos z)=\\
=(1/2)(2\cos z+j\sin z-j\sin z)=\\
=(1/2)(\cos z+j\sin z+\cos z-j\sin z)=\\
=(1/2)(e^{jz}+e^{-jz})
}
\SS{
\text{207}\\
x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
x(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+K_{p}m(t)]
}
\SS{
\text{208}\\
x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
\dfrac{d\phi(t)}{dt}=2\pi K_{f}m(t)\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow \phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\\
x(t)=A_{c}\cos\left[2\pi f_{c}t+2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\right]
}
\SS{
\text{208}\\
x(t)=A_{c}\cos\theta(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)]\\
\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b\\
\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
\phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau
}
\SS{
\text{208}\\
x(t)=A_{c}\cos\theta(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)]\\
\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b\\
\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
\phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau
}
\SS{
\text{208}\\
x(t)=A_{c}\cos\theta(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)]\\
\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b\\
\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
\phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau
}
\SS{
\text{265}\\
g(t)=f(t)\ast h(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\\
j(t)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT_{s})\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}[j(t)]=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}[\delta(t)]e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}\\
=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}
}
\SS{
\text{265}\\
g(t)=f(t)\ast h(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\\
j(t)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT_{s})\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}[j(t)]=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}[\delta(t)]e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}\\
=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}
}
\vfil
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

ALTERNATIVE APPROACH (without `\vfil` between blocks)

If one does not like the evenly spaced vertical column, and prefers a wide gap at column bottom, then defining

```
\def\SS#1{\noindent\addstackgap[3pt]{\Shortstack{#1}}\\}
```

seems to resolve that (and also adds a 3pt buffer above/below each stack), as in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}

%\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

%\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\stackalignment{l}
\setstackgap{S}{6pt}
\def\SS#1{\noindent\addstackgap[3pt]{\Shortstack{#1}}\\}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\SS{
\text{70}\\
e^{jz}=\cos z+j\sin z\\
\cos z=(1/2)(2\cos z)=\\
=(1/2)(2\cos z+j\sin z-j\sin z)=\\
=(1/2)(\cos z+j\sin z+\cos z-j\sin z)=\\
=(1/2)(e^{jz}+e^{-jz})
}
\SS{
\text{70}\\
e^{jz}=\cos z+j\sin z\\
\cos z=(1/2)(2\cos z)=\\
=(1/2)(2\cos z+j\sin z-j\sin z)=\\
=(1/2)(\cos z+j\sin z+\cos z-j\sin z)=\\
=(1/2)(e^{jz}+e^{-jz})
}
\SS{
\text{207}\\
x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
x(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+K_{p}m(t)]
}
\SS{
\text{208}\\
x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
\dfrac{d\phi(t)}{dt}=2\pi K_{f}m(t)\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow \phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\\
x(t)=A_{c}\cos\left[2\pi f_{c}t+2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\right]
}
\SS{
\text{265}\\
g(t)=f(t)\ast h(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\\
j(t)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT_{s})\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}[j(t)]=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}[\delta(t)]e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}\\
=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}
}
\SS{
\text{265}\\
g(t)=f(t)\ast h(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\\
j(t)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT_{s})\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}[j(t)]=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}[\delta(t)]e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}\\
=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}
}
\SS{
\text{265}\\
g(t)=f(t)\ast h(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\\
j(t)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT_{s})\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}[j(t)]=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}[\delta(t)]e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}\\
=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}
}
\vfil
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to change `\vspace{2ex}\par\vfil` with cm instead ex and when I used large numbers like 5 or 7 cm I saw a difference but when I used 1 or 2 or 0.5 cm nothing was happening. Why? If I want for instanse no gap between the stacks what can I do?

Comment: @Adam The minimum space between the blocks can be changed with the `2ex` in the definition of `\SS`.  The `vfil` in that same definition will force the gap after each item in the column to be "the same", so as to avoid an extra big gap at the bottom of the column.  I don't have experience with multicolumn, but its vertical justification algorithms seem strange to me.  I can manually add `\rule{0pt}{5ex}\par` after the last block in the 1st column to force space at the bottom of the column, but such a manual approach is not ideal.  Let me think more on it.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Why is that difficult?Why can't this just be a manual dicision writing for example \vspace{0ex}\par\vfil and to have your output? Also I didn't understand the role of the `vfil`.

Comment: @Adam See revision (bottom of answer).  The `\vfil` inserts a stretchy "rubber band" or "glue" between each stack.  If the stacks don't fill up the whole column, the glue stretches between the top and bottom margins, providing equal spacing between each stack.

Comment: Sorry for the questions but if I write text before a stack why the space between the lines is so small?

Comment: @Adam The stack leaves no space above and below it.  One fix would be `text\\~\\ \SS{...}`.  Otherwise, if you want, I could add a fixed space (e.g., 2 or 3pt) above and below each stack, but then it will be that far below the top margin.

Comment: @Adam Please see revision.

Comment: I saw it and I tried it. I kept the first one with the `\par\vfil`. It's far better.

Comment: @Adam I agree that `\vfil` form is better.  I also added the 3pt stacking gap to that 1st solution, so please revisit that code.

Comment: Ok I added the new feature. If I may ask If I don't use the `\par\vfil` why every stack creates a badbox?

Comment: @Adam I am not sure, but it could be because one is overstuffing the column, without leaving a natural breakpoint for the new column

Answer (score 2):

You aren't allowing LaTeX any place to split the columns; if you really have such gigantic displays, then tell

```
\allowdisplaybreaks
```

in your document preamble.

The initial vertical space is due to beginning a paragraph with a display environment, which is wrong.

Here's a more minimalistic example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
\raggedcolumns

\begin{multicols}{2}
70
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
&e^{jz}=\cos z+j\sin z\\
&\cos z=(1/2)(2\cos z)=\\
&=(1/2)(2\cos z+j\sin z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(\cos z+j\sin z+\cos z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(e^{jz}+e^{-jz})
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{207}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
&\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
&\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+K_{p}m(t)]
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{208}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
&\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
&\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}=2\pi K_{f}m(t)\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow \phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos\left[2\pi f_{c}t+2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau\right]
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{208}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos\theta(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)]\\
&\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b\\
&\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
&\phi(t)=2\pi K_{f}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}m(\tau)d\tau
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\text{265}\\
&g(t)=f(t)\ast h(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\\
&j(t)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT_{s})\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}[j(t)]=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}[\delta(t)]e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{j2\pi fkT_{s}}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Of course, balancing the columns is impossible because of the many `aligned`.

[image]

---

As an aside, note that `inputenc` should ***never*** be used when compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Thank you. But even if I have text to begin the paragraph then there is still the same vertical space. And what about the two `gather` environments? Why is there a problem with them?

Comment: @Adam I see no vertical space at the start. Two distinct display environments should *never* appear immediately one after the other.

Comment: I am talking about the space in my second image. For which space are you talking about? Why shouldn't they appear one after the other?

Comment: @Adam Well, that code is wrong under many respects, so why bother?

Comment: Haha I try not just to write correct code but to understand why it is wrong. But wait a minute the code you wrote in your answer you think is wrong?

Comment: @Adam Who said that? *Your* code in the second example is wrong. It's like saying “this hammer doesn't work, because it's difficult to cut meat with it”.

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant the whole execution.

Comment: I going to borrow your quote.  It seems the corollary to "If your only tool is a hammer, then soon every problem begins to look like a nail."

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @egreg if I don't place the 70 as a text outside the `align` then there is a space because as you said it is not proper to begin with a display environment. In the second column (I use `multicols*` there is no space although the 265 is in the `align`. Shouldn't there be space also there? Why is this different?

Comment: @Adam, I was commenting to egreg about his hammer/meat quote.  But now that I've got you, I want to understand the desired behavior.  You want a full block to remain unbroken, but if it get shifted to the next column, you want the top margins to stay aligned in each column.  Is that right?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I don't care if it is unbroken or not (basically I think that if they broke it would be better as there wouldn't be so much empty space in the first column). I want to write a lot of math so I use `gather` and `align` but I had a problem with vertical space and also with overfull boxes due to the fact that `gather` didn't break into another column.

Comment: @egreg is there an incompatibility between `amsmath` and `unicode-math`? When I use the latter then I get a badbox and the math don't break into another column. If I don't use it then it is fixed.

Comment: @Adam If I add `\usepackage{unicode-math}` to my code and compile with XeLaTeX, I get the same output.